# ASP.NET DropDownList not binding SQL on SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Title says the majority of whats going on. Basically I have two DropDownLists with one doing an SQL search based off the previous's value, which requires to update it every time it changes. This is my code:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Ship Model
        String str2 = "SELECT DISTINCT [Ship Model] FROM ShipMatrix WHERE ([Ship Make]='@ShipMake')";
        SqlCommand qry2 = new SqlCommand(str2, Xebon);
        qry2.Parameters.Add("ShipMake", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.Text;
        Connection.Open();
        qry2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda2.SelectCommand = qry2;
        DataTable ds2 = new DataTable();
        sda2.Fill(ds2);

        DropDownList2.DataSource = ds2;
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Ship Model";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "Ship Model";
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
        Connection.Close();
    }
```

Unfortunately it is not updating and the drop down remains about 2-3 characters long and has no values / texts.

Comment: Did you enable the `AutoPostBack` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have enabled AutoPostBack thanks to some of the suggestions here

Additionally my issue was with using "DropDownList.SelectedValue;" rather than "DropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();" after changing this everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Set AutoPostBack=true on DropDownList1.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Put @ sign prefix in sql parameter

```
qry2.Parameters.Add("@ShipMake", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.Text;
```

Comment: This is now sending a post back, however it is still not filling the other text box with data. Also does not do it when I trigger it manually in Page_Load. I am assuming it is an issue with the code and not with asp.net / HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
DropDownList1.Text
```

will not work here. If you want to compare the text of selected item from dropdown, you can use one of the following method.

```
qry2.Parameters.Add("@ShipMake", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

OR

```
qry2.Parameters.Add("@ShipMake", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
```